# What are the benefits of "String".equals(otherString)

Tags: java, string

in a tutorial (for implementing a xml parser) i saw the following code:

```
if( "NODENAME".equals(xmlreader.getNodeName()) ) {  // getNodeName() returns java.lang.String
... 
}
```

Is there a reason to write a string comparision like that?.

This may be some kind of best/bad practice or code like that could give some performance benefit. I would like to know if i should use this in commercial projects.

Comment: read here http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/147650

Comment: `if(constant == variable)` is sometimes called Yoda condition. It can be used to avoid typos like `constant = variable`, or `NullPointerExceptions` in Java.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That  saves you from  a `NullPointerException.`

That is [Yoda Condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_Conditions)  **used  to solve unsafe null behavior.**

> In programming jargon, Yoda Conditions (also called Yoda Notation) is a programming style where the two parts of an expression are reversed in a conditional statement.

Advantage is

> Swapping the two conditional values does not change the behavior of the program. A common mistake is to accidentally assign a value instead of writing a conditional statement.

Comment: I think it would be good to list disadvantages of using Yoda condition as well?

Answer (score 2):

Its called a [Yoda condition](http://united-coders.com/christian-harms/what-are-yoda-conditions/) and used to avoid `NullPointerException`. Regarding its use in commercial projects, this is really a design decision - some developers want to be protected against null values whereas others *want* the fail fast mechanism offered by the conventional notation.

Answer (score 2):

If you have code:

```
if( "NODENAME".equals(xmlreader.getNodeName()) ){...}
```

It will avoid `NullPointerException` when `xmlreader.getNodeName()` is `null` since

```
"NODENAME".equals(null)
```

will return false instead of `NullPointerException`.

**PS:** Keep in mind that if for some reason `xmlreader` itself is null then:

```
"NODENAME".equals(xmlreader.getNodeName())
```

can still throw `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 2):

Usually string comparison was written like that to avoid `NullPointerException` if `xmlreader.getNodeName()` is null, because then you would have

```
if("NODENAME".equals(null)) {
    // ... 
}
```

compared to

```
if(null.equals("NODENAME")) {
    // ... 
}
```

which would've thrown.

This is called Yoda condition:

[image]

if you expect `xmlreader.getNodeName()` to be `null` then it's ok, otherwise I would not rely on this to avoid the exception to be thrown, you should rather deal with it earlier on in your code.

Comment: Plus 1 for that sweet Yoda pic

Answer (score 0):

The method `equals()` checks for the contents of the `String`.
calling the `equals()` method on literal saves you from `NullPointerException` which may happen if `xmlReader.getNodeName()` returns `null`. Calling `equals` method on `null` will cause `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0):

If you have the impression that you could also compare the Strings using `==` then it would fail even if in the comparison would be involved two "meaningfully" equal String, since `==` checks if it is the same Object. Of course, as the other answers state, you avoid a `NullPointeException` if you call equals on a standard String, as in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Since equals is a built in method in java , we need to make sure that it should be called with object not with null. so in case if we call with null then we will endup with Null pointer exception.

**Ex : assume i need to check whether string a is equal to "hai" and a is coming from user.**

then i am not sure whether 'a' will be null or not. so if i use `a.equals("hai")` then its not safe if a becomes null but if you reverse the comparison then it is always safe no matter a is null or not.

so always prefer `"hai".equals(a)` to be safe from null pointer exception.