# Why doesn't this code terminate my program? Java

Tags: java, exit, terminate

I am trying to implement the `System.exit(0);` in java to terminate my program when the word "exit" is typed into the console. I wrote the following method:

```
    public static void exit(){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Str1 = input.next(String);

    if (str1 = "exit"){

        System.exit(0);
    }

    else if (str1 = "clear"){

        System.out.println("0.0");
    }       
}
```

and it doesn't seem to be working.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks
P.S the "clear" is just supposed to return 0.0 when "clear" is entered into the console, if you could not already tell.

Comment: If you would have googled how to compare strings you would have got your answer. :)

Comment: btw besides equals(), I think your codes got some minor mistakes. Str1 and str1 are different.

Comment: Has you debuged it? Is `System.exit(0)` called anyway?

Answer (score 4):

Compare strings with `equals()`  not with `==`.

The reason is that `==` just compares object references/primitives,where as String's `.equals()` method checks equality.

```
if (str1.equals("exit")){

}
```

and also

```
else if (str1.equals("clear")){

}
```

Might useful :[What are the benefits of "String".equals(otherString)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18611050/what-are-the-benefits-of-string-equalsotherstring/18611083#18611083)

Comment: better - `"exit".equals(str1)`

Answer (score 1):

```
if(str.equals("exit"))
```

or

```
if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("exit"))
```

or

```
if(str == "exit")
```

instead of

```
if (str1 = "exit"){
```

Answer (score 1):

With `if (str1 = "exit")` you use an allocation instead of a compare.
You can compare with the `equals()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `String.equals(String other)` function to compare strings, not the `==` operator.

The function checks the actual contents of the string, the `==` operator checks whether the references to the objects are equal.  Note that string constants are usually "interned" such that two constants with the same value can actually be compared with `==`, but it's better not to rely on that.

So use:

```
if ("exit".equals(str1)){

}
```

Comment: These were all very helpful, thank you.  However, I implemented these changes and the console is still throwing an exception rather than terminating the program.

Comment: Throwing what exception ? @CharlieTidmarsh

Comment: @CharlieTidmarsh Could you tell me your exception?

Answer (score 0):

Besides `equals()`, the `input.next(String pattern);` require pattern not `String` data type

Change your code to:

```
public static void exit(){   

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
str1 = input.next(); //assumed str1 is global variable

if (str1.equals("exit")){

    System.exit(0);
}

else if (str1.equals("clear")){

    System.out.println("0.0");
}

}
```

Notes : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_next_string.htm

Comment: Change `str1 = input.next();` to `String str1 = input.next();`, except if `str1` is a global variable