# if (text.equals("") Crashes

Tags: java, android, logging, crash

I have a textfield on my view, and when the text changes on the textfield i have a if statement, so when a certain keyword is in the textview, some code will run.  Here is my code for the if statement:

```
 if (text1.equals("rotate")) {


                red.setRotation(red.getRotation() + 5);

                blue.setRotation(blue.getRotation() + 5);


            }
```

but when text1 equals 'rotate' and its running this code, the app will crash.

Here is the log cat:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Means `text1` is `null`

Comment: Where is text1 initialized?

Comment: Always post your logcat in code in question. Never add it as picture.

Comment: If you did "rotate".equals( text1 ) it would not crash.

Comment: [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 5):

The reason for that is `text1` is null and you are trying to call a method on null reference.

Either you forgot to initialize it or no value assigned yet.

If you already have the initialization and if there are chances to get a null value, you need to have a guard condition for that.

```
 if (text1 !=null && text1.equals("rotate")) {
```

This first checks for null and then invoke the method.

Comment: Simply do "rotate".equals(text1) that should take care on NPE. you don't need to check for null.

Comment: @StackFlowed  [I know that, but cared for OP's beginner level :)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18611050/what-are-the-benefits-of-string-equalsotherstring/18611083#18611083)

Comment: Agreed. what about Apache StringUtils.isNotBlank(text1) ?

Comment: @StackFlowed Let OP learn the core things :) Then he optimize his codes with them.

Comment: Even if i use this code, the app still crashes. With the same log

Answer (score 1):

It appears like text1 is not initialized. In you method, initialize `text1`. Here's an *example* of how to:

```
text1   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text1);
```

If it is initialized and can have null, then guard it.

```
 if ("rotate".equals(text1)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

**First:** Initialise `text1`

If it is a `TextView` then

```
text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_id);
```

If it is a `EditText` then

```
text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_id);
```

**Second:** Compare it like this:

```
if (text1.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("rotate")) {
   red.setRotation(red.getRotation() + 5);
   blue.setRotation(blue.getRotation() + 5);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to initialise the `text1` object. From the log it is clear that the `text1` object is `null`.

You can then compare the string using:

```
if (text1 && "rotate".equals(text1.getText().toString()))
{
}
```